# How do you clear filter cache in pivot tables in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I have turned number of items to retain field to none and also tried the VBA macro in the link below. Neither worked and when I refresh my pivot table the filter still keeps items not being used. The only solution is to completely rebuild the pivot table but what's the point if the filter will keep those items when I try to use the pivot table again later.

https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4238-excel-clear-filter-cache.html

Answer (score 0):

I tested the code you provided from link. It works, when run it. You can run the code in VBA editor:

[image]

Comment: I have already used that code and ran it. It did nothing to the pivot tables essentially and I copied and pasted it exactly. That is why I'm trying to find another solution.